# Deformable torus not showing in pydrake port of C++ deformable torus example

Tags: drake

I tried porting the [C++ deformable torus example](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/examples/multibody/deformable_torus/deformable_torus.cc) to python but the torus is not showing up in meshcat.

There are no errors and I see the "ground" but not the torus:
[image: meshcat output]

(I didn't include the parts related to the gripper, just trying to get the torus to show up for now)

```
def run_demo():
    builder = DiagramBuilder()

    plant_config = MultibodyPlantConfig()
    plant_config.time_step = time_step
    plant_config.discrete_contact_solver = "sap"

    plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlant(plant_config, builder)

    rigid_proximity_props = ProximityProperties()
    surface_friction = CoulombFriction(1.15, 1.15)
    rigid_proximity_props.AddProperty("hydroelastic",
                                      "resolution_hint", 1.0)
    AddContactMaterial(friction = surface_friction,
                       properties = rigid_proximity_props)
    
    ground = Box(4, 4, 4)
    X_WG = RigidTransform(RotationMatrix(), [0, 0, -2])
    plant.RegisterCollisionGeometry(plant.world_body(), X_WG, ground,
                                    "ground_collision", rigid_proximity_props)
    plant.RegisterVisualGeometry(plant.world_body(), X_WG, ground,
                                 "ground_visual", [0.7, 0.5, 0.4, 0.8])

    owned_deformable_model = DeformableModel(plant)

    deformable_config = DeformableBodyConfig()
    deformable_config.set_youngs_modulus(E)
    deformable_config.set_poissons_ratio(nu)
    deformable_config.set_mass_density(density)
    deformable_config.set_stiffness_damping_coefficient(beta)

    scale = 0.65;
    torus_mesh = Mesh("./torus.vtk", scale)
    kL = 0.09 * scale
    X_WB = RigidTransform(RotationMatrix(), [0, 0, kL/2])
    torus_instance = GeometryInstance(X_WB, torus_mesh, "deformable_torus")

    deformable_proximity_props = ProximityProperties()
    AddContactMaterial(friction = surface_friction,
                       properties = deformable_proximity_props)
    torus_instance.set_proximity_properties(deformable_proximity_props)

    unused_resolution_hint = 1.0
    owned_deformable_model.RegisterDeformableBody(
        torus_instance, deformable_config, unused_resolution_hint)

    plant.AddPhysicalModel(owned_deformable_model)
    deformable_model = owned_deformable_model

    plant.Finalize();

    builder.Connect(
        deformable_model.vertex_positions_port(),
        scene_graph.get_source_configuration_port(plant.get_source_id()));
    
    MeshcatVisualizer.AddToBuilder(builder, scene_graph, meshcat)
    diagram = builder.Build()
    diagram_context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
    simulator = Simulator(diagram)
    simulator.Initialize()
    simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(realtime_rate)
    meshcat.AddButton("Stop Simulation", "Escape")

    while meshcat.GetButtonClicks("Stop Simulation") < 1:
        simulator.AdvanceTo(simulator.get_context().get_time() + 2.0)
        
    meshcat.DeleteButton("Stop Simulation")
    meshcat.DeleteAddedControls()
```

I'm thinking that the problem may be in the line: `plant.AddPhysicalModel(owned_deformable_model)`

or somewhere earlier in the process of creating the deformable model, but I'm not sure...

Full project here: [DeepNote project](https://deepnote.com/workspace/robotic-manipulation-sy-d2ecc637-23ba-44ee-9086-1f71c7a61920/project/deformablesdrake-be91f8e2-4133-4172-a912-f67848b23fe8/%2Fdeformable_torus.ipynb.ipynb)

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deformable body should have been added to the simulation already. You can verify this by checking `deformable_model.num_bodies()`.

This should be a visualization issue. As the README of the C++ example states, Meldis is required to visualize deformable bodies. You should be able to visualize after launching Meldis and switching the MeshcatVisualizer to DrakeVisualizer in your diagram.

Answer (score 0):

For switching to the meldis you should:

1. change

```
MeshcatVisualizer().AddToBuilder(builder, scene_graph)
```

on this

```
DrakeVisualizer().AddToBuilder(builder, scene_graph)
```

2. comment `meshcat` from file everywhere.
3. You can change

```
    while meshcat.GetButtonClicks("Stop Simulation") < 1:
        simulator.AdvanceTo(simulator.get_context().get_time() + 2.0)
```

on this

```
simulator.AdvanceTo(simulator.get_context().get_time() + 2.0)
```

4. This `meshcat = StartMeshcat()` isn't required.
5. You should before runnig file run `python3 -m pydrake.visualization.meldis` from terminal for opening `Meshcat listening`.