# Simulate deformable objects with drake

Tags: drake

I note that there is [DeformableModel](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_deformable_model.html) class in the drake documentation. Is simulating deformable objects (like cloth and rope) supported in drake now? If so, are there some examples of how to use drake for simulating deformable objects? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drake has incredibly good deformable body simulation in the pipeline ([see this video/paper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yugIJDkWR6M)). Parts of it are available now, and the latest results will arrive in Drake soon. The user guides / usability features will lag just behind.

For an example of what you can do with Drake right now, see the [C++ deformable torus example](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/f561342ef0498666a519b57d36d3b9c15bf8e12d/examples/multibody/deformable_torus/deformable_torus.cc) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74941609/9510020) about calling it from python.